# How to hide a field in a comment programatically?

Tags: php, drupal-7, field, drupal-comments

My comments have a field called 'Extra'. I'm trying to hide it when the user who's viewing the comment wrote it. This is my custom module:

```
function mymodule_comment_view($comment) {
  global $user;
  if ($comment->uid == $user->uid){
    unset ($comment->field_extra);
  }
}
```

Why isn't this working and what's the correct way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this code works:

```
function mymodule_comment_view($comment) {
  global $user;
  if ($comment->uid == $user->uid){
    $comment->content['field_extra']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to change to "hook" part of the function name to the name of your module?

```
function MODULENAME_comment_view($comment) {
  global $user;
  if ($comment->uid == $user->uid){
    unset ($comment->field_extra);
  }
}
```

The rest of the code should work. You shouldn't need to pass $comment by reference, so remove the "&"-character again if you still have it in.

Comment: Yes, I did. I'll clarify it in my question. I found the answer in the meantime.